# VueJS How to Change Data Variable from a Function within Methods

Tags: vue.js

I have searched and to no avail cannot find a working solution to my problem.

I am using Vue 3.1.3

The issue I seem to be running into has something to do with accessing a variable stored in `data()` from within a method and changing that variable.

Line 52, my goal is within `axios.post` if there is an error I want to catch it and then change the variable, `failedLogin`, within data, to true.

Currently it is just set to `this.failedLogin = true` as I read in Vue documentation this is all you should need to be able to do, however I believe this is only if it is at the top of the methods and not within a function within methods.

I have tried some other solutions such as

- `this.$set(this.failedLogin, true);`
- `this.failedLogin.value = true`

https://pastebin.com/sR1bB72v

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks. Read the warning about arrow functions, the same applies to functions under `methods`.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the login function should be created at the same level as data and methods, not as an arrow function, and then the function should be run within method?

Comment: No, just make `login` a regular function. e.g., from `login:(e, key)=>{` to `login(e, key){`. Remove the `:` and the `=>`, that's it.

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood? I have tried to remove the : and the =>

https://pastebin.com/HK21sCS6

But I am receiving Unexpected token, expected , (44:12)

Comment: Nevermind I had a formatting error! You are awesome, this was exactly my problem!